# PHP simplexml_load_file not parsing

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

As you can see I've checked some other answers here on Stackoverflow but I only get blank results. Here's what I've got so far:

```
$city = simplexml_load_file('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Tijuana&mode=xml&appid=12fcd235af3a27a895aecb26bc957055');

echo $city['current']['city']['name'];
echo $city->current->city;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this `echo (string)$city->city["name"];` `simplexml_load_string` or `file` ignore root element, which is `current` in your case

Comment: One last question: Sahil, I can get the result for the first pocket but not the second... for example:
        <?php
        $base_clima = simplexml_load_file('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Tijuana&mode=xml&appid=12fcd235af3a27a895aecb26bc957055');
    // print_r($city);
     $humedad = (string)$base_clima->humidity["value"];
     $wind_v = (string)$base_clima->wind["speed"]['value'];
 
     ?>
    <p><?='Humidity: '.$humedad.'%'?></p>
    <p><?='Wind speed: '. $wind_v .'Km/h'?></p>

Comment: I dont understand which second pocket ?

Comment: Sorry... Object.
If I want to print the first part of the array inside of the wind objet I get a blank result.  wind["speed"]->speed["value"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code change this:

```
$base_clima->wind["speed"]['value'];
```

**This:**

```
$base_clima->wind->speed['value'];
```

**Sample print of an object:**

```
[wind] => SimpleXMLElement Object
         (
            [speed] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 1.95
                            [name] => Light breeze
                        )

                )
         )
```

For accessing the elements of an object You can use something like this  `$object->element1->element2` but in `simplexml_load_string/file` `@attributes` can be accessed as an array so you can use it like this.

Try this, Hope this one will be helpful.

```
$city = simplexml_load_file('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Tijuana&mode=xml&appid=12fcd235af3a27a895aecb26bc957055');
echo $humedad = (string)$city->humidity["value"]; 
echo $wind_v = (string)$city->wind->speed['value'];
```

Comment: You are a Genus! 
Thanks a lot.